# Nuxt Module cannot find itself

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

./AppGallery.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=0cb54319&lang=scss&scoped=true& in ./components/sub-page/AppGallery.vue

AppGalery.vue doesn't import anything

```
<template>
    <div class="gallery" v-if="pictures">
        <a v-for="(picture, index) in pictures" :key="index" class="gallery__item" :href="picture.path" data-lightbox="gallery" :data-title="picture.title">
            <div class="gallery__image">
                <img :src="picture.path">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery__description" v-if="options.showDescription">{{ picture.title }}</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'AppGallery',

    props: {
        pictures: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },

        options: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
            default() {
                return {
                    showDescription: true,
                };
            },
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        //lightbox.build();
    },
};
</script>
```

On save error changes to other file.